# Booting Windows from HDD, apps from SSD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd

My question is that, if my OS is on HDD and I install something on SSD, for example a game, will the game start&load faster or i need to install my OS on the SSD?

Answer (score 0):

Basically from what I know:
Games installed on an SSD, means all the files from the Game are located on your SSD, load faster, yes.
But there are a few more things to think of. For example, if you install a game with steam, some files are still located on the disk, where the OS is installed, means the difference is not that big.

Comment: The problem is that my OS is burnt on my motherboard. I can't reinstall it. So i guess my best option is that I install my games on SSD and it may load up faster.

Comment: @Deddj since you can't change anything related to your OS, this would be the simpliest and best option you could go with... there's not really more that you could do...